# Yii Framework Captcha conflict with beforeAction() function

Tags: yii

I have app in Yii and i extend all classes from some base controller and i have these code in it :

```
protected function beforeAction($action)
    {
        $this->setglobalvariable();
        return parent::beforeAction($action);
    }
```

as i just understand , these code prevent the Captcha to show , because when i delete it , the captcha shows up ! the captcha function is :

```
public function actions()
    {
        return array(
            // captcha action renders the CAPTCHA image displayed on the contact page
            'captcha'=>array(
                'class'=>'CCaptchaAction',
                'backColor'=>0xFFFFFF,
                'minLength'=>2,
                'maxLength'=>3,
                'width'=>60,
            ),
            // page action renders "static" pages stored under 'protected/views/site/pages'
            // They can be accessed via: index.php?r=site/page&view=FileName
            'page'=>array(
                'class'=>'CViewAction',
            ),
        );
    }
```

So how could i use beforeAction and captcha in same time ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The confilict is in your structure , Show us more code . put the program in fresh yii and test it.

Comment: I put it in fresh Yii and it work and i found my error.it is mo structure.

Answer (score 1):

beforeAction function , Do not have any conflict with other Yii methods or functions.

The probelm is in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously there is some code in your *Controller::setglobalvariables()* method that conflicts with the captcha's code.

The *CCaptachAction::run()* method uses **$_GET** parameters. Are you somehow resetting $_GET ?

Can you show us the code ?